# .htaccess access restriction not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

just moved our website to a vps from shared web hosting and all of a sudden users can browse directories. my .htaccess file has code in it that stopped that on the last server but now it's being ignored.

I added this to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf but it doesn't seem to have helped

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

the container is running ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is related to the Order directive.

Try to modify the lines as shown below:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

More information can be found here: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order

Comment: I changed the one under `<Directory /var/www/>` in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and it's working now :) nice to know people can't download my php files now...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `Options -Indexes` in your htaccess or virtual host.

Comment: .htaccess says `DirectoryIndex login.php
IndexIgnore *`